# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 72

Tags: java, android

When I am reading numbers from contact book, then i replace the contact number by using the below code

```
String  number ="+91 97-00-0000000";
String  numberValue =number.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
```

And i am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 72:
```

I have already encoded this number i.e `numberValue = URLEncoder.encode(number, "UTF-8");`

it crashes with the same exception.

Comment: You can try by removing all non-numeric characters with _number.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");_.

Comment: Your code is confusing - you've provided two different ways of getting `numberValue`. If you're using `URLEncoder.encode`, where does the `replaceAll` code come in? It would really help if you'd provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I tried both way but it crashes.

Comment: I tried the code:
`String  number ="+91 97-00-0000000";
String  numberValue = number.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
numberValue = URLEncoder.encode(number, "UTF-8");
System.out.println(numberValue); `, and is running without exception.

Comment: thanks this code is working number.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

String  number ="+91 97-00-0000000";
String  numberValue =number.replaceAll("(?<=\\d) +(?=\\d)", "%20");
```